# How do I add a Picture to a JFrame by adding a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, bufferedimage

I have a problem with my code here. I want to set the Background of a JFrame by adding a JLabel which I drew the image on.

But its not showing the img, btw the Image is read correctly(No Exception).

I'm working with multiple classes: Var.java, Label.java, Gui.java  -> All are in the same package

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new Gui();
        new Label();
        new Var();
        new KeyHandler();
    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Gui {

    public Gui() {
        
        Var.jf1 = new JFrame();
        Var.jf1.setSize(Var.breite, Var.höhe);
        Var.jf1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Var.jf1.setLayout(null);
        Var.jf1.setTitle("Meriadoc Brandybock");
        Var.jf1.setResizable(false);
        Var.jf1.requestFocus();
        Var.jf1.addKeyListener((KeyListener) new KeyHandler());
        Var.jf1.setVisible(true);
        
        Var.lbl1 = new Label();
        Var.lbl1.setBounds(0, 0, Var.breite, Var.höhe);
        Var.lbl1.setVisible(true);
        Var.jf1.add(Var.lbl1);
        
        
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Label extends JLabel{

    protected void paintcomponent(Graphics g){
    
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        
        g.drawImage(Var.b1, 0, 0, 1000, 600, null);
        
        repaint();
        
    }

}
```

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Var {

    
    static JFrame jf1;
    static Label lbl1;
    
    static int breite = 1000;
    static int höhe = 600;
    
    static boolean moveUP = false;
    static boolean moveDOWN = false;
    static boolean moveRIGHT = false;
    static boolean moveLEFT = false;
    
    static BufferedImage b1;
    

    
    
    public Var() {
        
        try {
            Var.b1 = ImageIO.read(new File("rsc/b1.png"));
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Background konnte nicht geladen werden");
        }
        
    }

}
```

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Comment: Many problems: 1) You should NOT be using static variables. There is no need to use them and the fact you are using them implies a poor design of your classes. 2) the point of using a JLabel is that a JLabel will do the painting of the ImageIcon for you. There is no need to do custom painting. If for some reason you need to do custom painting then you extend JComponent or JPanel. 3) Swing was designed to be using with layout managers. Don't use a null layout.

Comment: To learn the basics of Swing I suggest you start by reading [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html). Download the working code and modify it for your requirements. You can also check out [Background Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/) for more information about adding a background image to a frame.